# Transferring a 2D array into a file and back

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, filereader, filewriter

I've looked around at similar questions, but I'm still stuck on this bit of code.

```
public class MasterMindSaveLoad extends Board {
    public void saveGame() {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("saveGame.txt"));
            for (int i=0; i<numPegs; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<numColours; j++) {
                    oos.writeObject(Board[i][j]);
                }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<numPegs; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<numColours; j++) {
                    oos.writeObject(Feedback[i][j]);
                }
            }

        }
    public void loadGame(String savedGame) {
        try {

        } catch (MasterMindFileFormatException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I have been given a really rough layout for saving a 2D array into a file and reading back from it. I was not sure how to go about it, and this is as much as I've got so far. I have to actually save two 2D arrays, and then when reading, I have to put them back into their own arrays again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can handle your 2D array as an object

```
Board[][] board = new Board[][]; 
Object ob = board;
```

then you can simply serialize and deserialize this object with the ObjectInputStream

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("saveGame.txt"));
oos.writeObject(board); //simply write the entire object
```

to retrive the data you just read it back:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileReader("saveGame.txt"));
Object o = ois.read();
board = (Board[][])o; //cast back to 2d array
```

use this technique for the `Feedback[][]` as well

have a look at this tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/2452/java-serialization-example-tutorial-serializable-serialversionuid

Comment: When I use "Board[][] board = new Board[][]" I get the error *array dimension missing* and the same for Feedback[][].

Comment: of course, that part is only for explanation (pseudo-code)... you have already defined the board somewhere in your code...  just ignore the first code block and look only at the serialization and deserialization

Comment: you could post how your `Board` looks like (add some code)...  and then i can give a more specific answer

Comment: ignoring the first code block, what should I place as board?

Comment: It's quite a bit of code, i'll add it but it might not make sense. Would it be easier if I told you all Board and Feedback contain are "B", "W", and "-"

Comment: just serialize/deserialize the entire object! that's the very point of my answer...

Comment: I still do not get it, I am not sure which part is the serializing and deserializing, and because you mentioned 'ignore the first code block' I tried replacing board with Board[][] but it still does not work.